# Imputation on the test set with fancyimpute

Tags: python, missing-data, imputation, fancyimpute

The python package [Fancyimpute](https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute) provides several methods for the imputation of missing values in Python. The documentation provides examples such as:

```
# X is the complete data matrix
# X_incomplete has the same values as X except a subset have been replace with NaN

# Model each feature with missing values as a function of other features, and
# use that estimate for imputation.
X_filled_ii = IterativeImputer().fit_transform(X_incomplete)
```

This works fine when applying the imputation method to a dataset `X`. But what if a `training/test` split is necessary? Once

```
X_train_filled = IterativeImputer().fit_transform(X_train_incomplete)
```

is called, how do I impute the test set and create `X_test_filled`? The test set needs to be imputed using the information from the training set. I guess that `IterativeImputer()` should returns and object that can fit `X_test_incomplete`. Is that possible?

Please note that imputing on the whole dataset and then split into training and test set is **not correct**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package looks like it mimic's scikit-learn's API. And after looking in the source code, it looks like it does have a [`transform`](https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute/blob/master/fancyimpute/iterative_imputer.py#L952) method.

```
my_imputer = IterativeImputer()
X_trained_filled = my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train_incomplete)

# now transform test
X_test_filled = my_imputer.transform(X_test)
```

The imputer will apply the same imputations that it learned from the training set.